# Multiple view join in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that is pulling from a stored procedure. Nothing wrong there, it works just fine in Visual Studio (right click on dataset, select query) and when executed in SSMS:

```
SELECT 
    asset as add_asset
    ,[desc] as add_desc
    ,start_dt as add_start_dt
    ,est_life as add_est_life
    ,acq_cost as add_acq_cost
    ,acc_depr as add_acc_depr
    ,lst_depr_yr as add_lst_depr_yr
    ,new_bk_val as add_new_bk_val
    ,[function_code] as add_function
    ,function_rollup as add_function_rollup
    ,fama_status as add_fama_status
    ,fama_fisc_yr as add_fama_fisc_yr
    ,fama_fst_yr as add_fama_fst_yr
    ,disp_fy as add_disp_fy
    ,spma_old as prev_book
    --,fahs_amt
FROM
    vw_Fixed_Asset_Audit_Sheet AS faas

INNER JOIN mu_live.dbo.spmaudit
ON spma_key = faas.asset

--INNER JOIN mu_live.dbo.fa_history
--ON a_asset_number = faas.asset

WHERE (
        (fama_status LIKE @acctstatus) 
        AND (function_rollup BETWEEN @frstart AND @frend)
    )
    AND (
        fama_fst_yr = @year
    )
    AND (
        spma_field = 'fama_cur_val'
        AND spma_action = 'P'
        AND YEAR(spma_date) = @year
    )
    /*AND (
        fahs_reason = 'DE'
        AND fahd_dr_cr = 'D'
        AND YEAR(fahs_eff_date) = @year
    )*/
ORDER BY asset ASC
```

Notice the commented code, that's the part that pulls a relevant field from another table. When I uncomment that code, it pulls the field and data correctly in SSMS. But in Visual Studio, I get no data. There's no error, and it even updates the field listing in the dataset in the "Report Data" pane with the new field (fahs_amt), but there's no records. I am at a complete loss as to why this query would fail like this without an error. Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: I should add, vw_Fixed Asset_Audit_Sheet is a view, spmaudit is a table, and fa_history is a view. They do exist inside different databases, but that shouldn't matter because they run just fine in SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Looks like SSRS doesn't like views when joining. I directly joined the underlying table in the fa_history view and it works just fine.